# Codazzi-Mainardi Equation $(\overline R(U,V)W,X) = -((\nabla_U\mathrm{II})(V,W),X) + ((\nabla_V\mathrm{II})(U,W),X)$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f:(M, g) \rightarrow (N, h)$ be a pseudo-Riemannian immersion, $\overline D$ the linear connection on $f^*(TN)$ induced from the Levi-Civita connection of $h$, and $\nabla$ the connection induced on the normal bundle $NM$ (which is the orthogonal complement of $TM$ in $f^*(TN)$). Consider also the second fundamental form
$$\mathrm{II}: TM\otimes TM\rightarrow NM$$
given by
$$\mathrm{II}(U,V) = \mathcal N(\overline D_U V),$$
where $\mathcal N$ is the orthogonal projection onto $NM$.

Then, how can I prove the Codazzi-Mainardi Equation
$$(\overline R(U,V)W,X) = -((\nabla_U\mathrm{II})(V,W),X) + ((\nabla_V\mathrm{II})(U,W),X),$$
where $U,V,W$ are vector fields on $M$, $X$ is a section of $NM$, and $\overline R$ is the curvature of $\overline D$ c.f. Arthur Besse’s “Einstein Manifolds” p. 38 Theorem 1.72 d)?

Comment: You need to read some standard differential/Riemannian geometry texts before reading Besse. Learn DoCarmo or Spivak volumes 2 and 3.